# Get content of file in some commit without using `git checkout`

Tags: git, git-commit, git-checkout

Is there a way to get a full content of a file (not just diff) in some commit, without using `git checkout` (because it pollutes the working directory)?
Something like this:

```
$ git content 43fb721 --file main.rb => "class Main\nend\r"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ git show HEAD~4:main.rb
$ git show <commit>:<filename>
```

Is exactly what I needed.